# How to call Excel UDF (*.XLL) function from R

Tags: r, excel, user-defined-functions, xll

I've got some Excel UDF functions written in C and compiled to XLL add-in file.
Function itself is a data-subscription service (retrieves data according to request parameters)

Is it possible to call those XLL defined functions from R?

Answer (score 1):

I think the very short answer is *Not a chance*.  The reason being is that you need the Visual Studio stack for Excel, that very stack does not mesh with R. We do have [Rcpp FAQ 2.9](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-FAQ.pdf) on this.

The longer answer is that you have working C code. You can add that to R in a package. [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) can help.